# Error: Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read. On changing provider from SQLOLEDB to MSOLEDBSQL

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, adodb, sqloledb

On change of provider from SQLOLEDB to MSOLEDBSQL in the ADODB connection string, we get the error:

> -2147217864 Row cannot be located for updating. Some values may have been changed since it was last read.

The connection string is:

```
Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;SERVER=servername;APP=Applicationname;DATABASE=databasename;WSID=id;Trusted_Connection=yes;MARS Connection=True;DataTypeCompatibility=80
```

And the code looks like:

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient 
rs.Open("SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 1 = 2", Adoconnection, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic, CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText) 
rs.AddNew
'Add the fields
...
...
rs.UpdateBatch ''this line throws error
```

Now, when in the connection string of provider is changed to SQLOLEDB, with the same code it works great without any issue.

Comment: Then why use MSOLEDBSQL?

Comment: As Microsoft says "SQLOLEDB is not maintained anymore and it is not recommended to use this driver for new development." and MSOLEDBSQL, provides security updates, datatype compatibility, mars features, and many others

Answer (score 1):

I found out the issue, it was in the SQL triggers.

The respective table had some update statements on the trigger. Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` just before the update statement in the trigger helped me to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks! This was the case for me. Had the same error as in the question. But the cause was the trigger and not the provider for the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a timestamp, or so called "rowversion" column to the table. (use type timestamp - which has ZERO to do with time).

Also, if you have any bit columns in that table, then make sure they are not null, and make sure a default value of (0) is set for that bit column.

And if the application has linked tables, then re-link your tables after you made the above change server side.

Comment: We already have timestamp or so called "rowversion" column :) and none of the bit column have null value, all have default value.

Comment: If this is being called from a form, then right before the above code do a me.Dirty = false and then run your code.

Answer (score 0):

I found my way to this thread because I had a similar error.  I am using Access 365 VBA 32-bit on Windows 10.  Here's a snippet of my code (some details omitted):

```
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = GetCurrentConnection()
cmd.CommandText = sql

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

With rs
    .Fields("FailedImport") = True
    .Fields("ImportErrors") = ReadErrorsFromResponse(xmlDoc)
    .Update
End With
```

I also encountered the same error as in the OP.  In my case, I didn't get the error until I included the update to the boolean field called `FailedImport`.  I found my way to [this forum post](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=38147) from 2008, containing this comment (formatting mine):

> Had same error, however had it with recordsets rather than data control.
> From another forum, I learnt that if you are using a static cursor for the recordset, using `adLockBatchOptimistic` instead of `adLockOptimistic` solved the problem.

So, I changed this line:
`rs.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic`

to this:
`rs.Open cmd, , adOpenDynamic, adLockBatchOptimistic`

And my code worked again!  Hope this helps someone else in the future!